# Background service silently Killed on some devices after some time

Tags: android, service, background-service

Background service silently Killed on some devices after some time. On some devices it is working continuously. But in these devices like (**Samsung Galaxy** Core Prime Android 5.0 & **Samsung S7**, Android 6) automatically stopped. Service `returns START_STICKY`  from `onStartCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

Call your service again in **onDestroy()**. The service will be restarted every time it is being killed by Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only working on an android 5 or 6 then there is a lot that you can do. When you get to Oreo it becomes much harder.

First a note about why your service is stopping. The background operations, which are not declared to run in the foreground, will eventually stop working relative to the processing power required by the service and the duration since the event was called. However, this will not kill your service this will simply pause it and restart it later. This pausing only occurs because there are significantly low resources available and apps running in the foreground require all supplementary processing powers.

If this is the case then waiting for the onDestory() function to be called won't help because the service isn't being called, it being paused. To ensure that this won't happen, I recommend running a foreground service. Android have said that pausing foreground services won't theoretically happen.

If you're determined to have the service run continually then you might try setting up an explicit broadcast receiver, that is routinely has items sent to it from the service. Then when a particular amount of time has passed without the broadcast receiver getting input then attempt to restart the service. This still might not be effective if the app as a whole is being paused. If you like the sound of that comment and like my comment and I'll test it out.